# NodeJS using a module from different files

Tags: node.js, module, require

Lets say that I would like to configure and use the `passport` module.

In my `app.js`, I have minimal module configuration like the following:

```
passport = require('passport'); // load module
app.use(passport.initialize()); // initialize passport
app.use(passport.session());    // use session
```

Now, I would like to configure routes for my app. However, I have this on a separate file, namely `./lib/router.js`. The question is whether I should be passing my configured `passport` variable over to that file, or `require` again the passport module in that file.

To illustrate:

```
// **app.js**
router = express.Router() // declare router
// option (A) Do I have to pass the passport variable to be using that same variable I have already defined in app.js?
app.use(require('./lib/router')(router, passport))

// **lib/router.js**
// option (B) or, can I just 'require' another passport module and affect the same module said in app.js?
passport = require('passport')
module.exports = (router) ->
    router.get('/authenticate', passport.authenticate('local'))
```

I hope the explanation is clear. I would also like to know the "preferred" practice in such cases where a module is used in multiple locations (`mongoose` is yet another module where different files require it to declare a model).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport packages exports an instance of the Passport class, so if you do:

```
var passport = require('passport');
```

in your route, you will be using the same instance.

From the source code of Passport library:

```
exports = module.exports = new Passport();
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm not understanding correctly, but if requiring creates an instance of the class, doesn't that mean that the two different instances don't affect each other?

Comment: There aren't two instances because the code within the required file is always executed once, so in other words, *passport* var is Singleton. When you require it, it always gives you the same instance.

Comment: I see. I think the confusion was that `new Passport()` is run every time the module is required. But instead, the module is exporting "an" instance of the class.